# Add target to cell but having local variables create issues swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a custom cell class. I have a button in a cell to which I have to add a target. But to do so, I have to implement a function for the action with the @objc keyword which I can't do as a nested function. Yes I have to make nested functions because of local variables such as indexPath and cell. Thanks

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "itemCellSub", for: indexPath) as! newInvoicePopup_ItemTableViewCell
        cell.textLabel!.text = (filteredItems[indexPath.row] as! ItemData).name
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = (filteredItems[indexPath.row] as! ItemData).tax
        cell.priceLabel!.text = (filteredItems[indexPath.row] as! ItemData).price
        cell.addButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(connected(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)


        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Can You Explain Whats The Issue ??

Comment: I want to add the connected function in the the function below but Xcode says me that objc keyword cannot be used within the function below.

Comment: Why Don't You Use Call Back function Using Closure ?

Comment: If You Don't Knw Abt That Then Let Me Know I'll Share Demo

Comment: yeah pls, it will be great. Thanks a lot !